# Alternative way to apply css properties without having id attributes

Tags: html, css

HTML code:

```
<section>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</section>
```

CSS code:

```
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
div:nth-child(1) {
    background:red; 
}
div:nth-child(2) {
    background:yellow;  
}
div:nth-child(3) {
    background:green;   
}
```

Is there a better way to define different color in each box? I do not want to use ids for the divs.

Comment: If you refuse to give the divs their own ids, how do you expect to *identify* each individual div?

Comment: "Better" is relative ... but another option is use specific class like `box red`

Comment: @DaniP Avoid presentational classes.

Comment: @Oriol it's just an example ... `red` to make it clear to OP

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered multiple classes?

HTML Code:

```
<section>
  <div class="box box-red"></div>
  <div class="box box-yellow"></div>
  <div class="box box-green"></div>
</section>
```

CSS Code:

```
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.box-red {
    background: red;
}
.box-yellow {
    background: yellow;
}
.box-green {
    background: green;
}
```

Hope this helps.